# Rails - set "default :from" dynamically in order to respond the email to the person that send the message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I have a contact form with this fields: name, email, subject, message. I send the email without problem.

What I need to do is: When you have the email in your inbox (Gmail, Outlook, Roundcube, etc) and you press **"reply"** in the **"to"** option, put the email of the person that sent the message instead of "email@example.com".

This is my contact_controller.rb

```
  def create
        @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
        respond_to do |format|
            if @contact.save
                if params[:contact_radio] === "sales"
                    SalesMailer.send_sales_email(@contact).deliver
                        format.html { redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
                        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
                else
                    WarrantyMailer.send_warranty_email(@contact).deliver
                        format.html { redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
                        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
                end
            else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end
```

This is my mailer:

```
class WarrantyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  #default :from => %(<#{email}>)

  def send_warranty_email(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail( :to => "carlos@dccolorweb.com",
    :subject => 'Contact Us Email')
    #:from => "contact#{email}")
  end
end
```

This is just a contact form. So, there's no logged users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more argument to your function

```
def send_warranty_email(contact, sender)
  @contact = contact
  mail( :to => "carlos@dccolorweb.com",
  :subject => 'Contact Us Email')
  :from => sender)
end
```

And when you call it in controller, pass current user email to it:

```
WarrantyMailer.send_warranty_email(@contact, current_user.email)
```

Comment: In my case, I don't have a logged user. I'm not sure if current_user.email will work.

Comment: Where do you keep the user info?

Comment: I have a model for the users. But, because this is just a Contact Form, I don't need to store the data in the users table. Instead, I have contact.rb model in order to store the content of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

On the mailer class, I just passed the email to the method and I created the corresponding variable:

```
class WarrantyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  #default :from => %(<#{email}>)

  def send_warranty_email(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail( :to => "carlos@dccolorweb.com",
    :subject => 'Contact Us Email')
    #:from => "contact#{email}")
  end
end
```

On my controller, I just passed the variable like this:

```
WarrantyMailer.send_warranty_email(@contact, @email).deliver
```